# Payslip generation program in c

Tags: c

this is the question:

> Write an interactive program to generate pay slips for the staff of size 12 employees (2 members are clerks, one computer operator, 6 salesmen, 3 helpers) , working in a small chemist retail shop.  Assumptions can be made wherever necessary. The payslip should display the employee no., employee name, no. of days worked during the month,  date of generation of the payslip, month for which the salary is being paid, all the details of the payment, deductions, gross-pay and net-pay.

when i run the program, it says invalid pointer, even though i havent used a pointer
i am can anyone let me know what mistake(s) are there in this program?

```
 #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    char name[30][30], designation[20[20], empid[12][12];
    int i;
    int n = 12;
    int working_days = 27;
    float basic[12], days_absent[12], days_present[12], gross_salary[20], pf[12], allowance[12], net[12];

    void enter_details_of_employee();
    void display();
    void get_time();

    void main()
    {
    int k;
    printf("Enter 1 to enter employee details and 2 to display salary\n");
    scanf("%d", &k);

    if(k == 1)
    {
    enter_details_of_employee();
    }
    else if(k == 2)
    {
    display();
    get_time();
    }
    else
    {
    printf("invalid choice");
    }
    }


    void enter_details_of_employee ()
    {
    int choice;
    int clerk_counter = 0, operator_counter = 0, salesman_counter = 0, helper_counter = 0, max = 0;

    do {

    printf("\n enter details of employees\n");

    printf("enter employee name\n");
    scanf("%c", &name);

    printf("enter employee id\n");
    scanf("%c", &empid);

    printf("enter your choice for employee designation\n 1.clerk \n 2.computer operator\n 3. salesman\n 4.helper\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if (choice == 1)
    {
    if(clerk_counter == 2)
            {
                printf("sorry, you have already entered the details of all clerks\n");
            }

                else

            {
                designation = "clerk";
                basic = 8000.00;
                printf("enter no of days absent\n");
                scanf("%d", &days_absent);
                days_present = working_days - days_absent;
                gross_salary = basic - ((days_absent / working_days) * basic);
                pf = gross_salary*0.1;
                allowance = gross_salary*0.55;
                net = (gross - pf) + allowance;
                clerk_counter++;

            }



        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
                if(operator_counter == 1)
            {
                printf("sorry, you have already entered the details of all computer operators\n");
            }

                else

            {
                designation = "computer operator";
                basic = 9000;
                printf("enter no of days absent\n);
                scanf("%d", &days_absent);
                days_present = working_days - days_absent;
                gross_salary = basic - ((days_absent / working_days) * basic);
                pf = gross_salary*0.12;
                allowance = gross_salary*0.75;
                net = (gross - pf) + allowance;
                operator_counter++;

            }


        }

        else if (choice == 3)
        {
                if(salesman_counter == 6)
            {
                printf("sorry, you have already entered the details of all salesman\n");
            }

                else

            {
                designation = "salesman";
                basic = 10000;
                printf("enter no of days absent\n);
                scanf("%d", &days_absent);
                days_present = working_days - days_absent;
                gross_salary = basic - ((days_absent / working_days) * basic);
                pf = gross_salary*0.15;
                allowance = gross_salary*0.95;
                net = (gross - pf) + allowance;
                salesman_counter++;

            }


        }

    else if (choice == 4)
        {
                if(salesman_counter == 3)
            {
                printf("sorry, you have already entered the details of all helpers\n");
            }

                else

            {
                designation = "helper";
                basic = 6500;
                printf("enter no of days absent\n);
                scanf("%d", &days_absent);
                days_present = working_days - days_absent;
                gross_salary = basic - ((days_absent / working_days) * basic);
                pf = gross_salary*0.08;
                allowance = gross_salary*0.45;
                net = (gross - pf) + allowance;
                helper_counter++;

            }


    }

    else
        {
    printf("invalid choice");
        }

        }
        while (max!=12);
        }

    void get_time()
    {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);

    printf("now: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
    }

    void display()
    {
    printf("SALARY SLIP OF EMPLOYEES ";
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("empid\t name\t days_absent\t days_present\t gross_salary\t   PF\t allowance\t net");
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf(empid[i][i] name[i][i] basic[i] days_absent[i] days_present[i] gross_salary[i] pf[i] allowance[i] net);
    }

    }
```

Comment: you have used pointers implicitly; arrays (e.g. basic[12]) and pointers are equivalent in C

Comment: & you have a typo designation[20[20]. Always good to submit code that compiles!

Comment: umm can you please elaborate a bit? thanks!

Comment: `scanf("%c", &name);` would be `scanf("%s", name[index]);`

Comment: Also, too many global variables.

Comment: @Bathsheba No, pointers and arrays are not equivalent.

Comment: Ok Carbonic Acid, almost equivalent ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba In certain situations, arrays decay (are implicitly converted) to a pointer to their first element.

Answer (score 0):

Errors:

1) Syntax Error 1:

```
char name[30][30], designation[20[20], empid[12][12];  // Bracket mismatch
```

2) Syntax Error 2:

```
char designation[20[20];
designation = "clerk";    // What is this?? ..the invalid pointer error
```

3) Find rest yourself or try compiling with `-Wall` option.

Answer (score 0):

```
here is a modified program, any feedback??

#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct mystruct{
char name[30];
char designation[20];
char empid[8];
float basic;
float days_absent;
float days_present;
float gross_salary;
float pf;
float allowance;
float net;
int counter;
int clerk_counter;
int operator_counter;
int salesman_counter;
int helper_counter;
char *next;
}mystruct;

char *p;


void enter_details_of_employee();
void display();
void get_time();

void main()
{
do
{
int k, choice;
printf("Enter 1 to enter employee details and 2 to display salary\n");
scanf("%d", &k);

if(k == 1)
{
p = (mystruct*)malloc(sizeOf(mystruct));
enter_details_of_employee();
}
else if(k == 2)
{
display();
get_time();
}
else
{
choice = 0;
printf("invalid choice, press 1 to continue\n");
}
}
while choice == 1;
}

void enter_details_of_employee ()
{
if(p->mystruct.counter!=12)
{
int proceed = 1;

do
{
printf("\n enter details of employees\n");

printf("enter employee name\n");
scanf("%u", &p->mystruct.name);

printf("enter employee id\n");
scanf("%u", &p.empid);

printf("enter your choice for employee designation\n 1.clerk \n 2.computer operator\n 3. salesman\n 4.helper\n");
scanf("%d", &choice);

if (choice == 1)
{
if(p->mystruct.clerk_counter == 2)
        {
            printf("sorry, you have already entered the details of all clerks\n");
        }

            else

        {
            p->mystruct.designation = "clerk";
            p->mystruct.basic = 8000.00;
            printf("enter no of days absent\n");
            scanf("%u", &p->mystruct.days_absent);
            p->mystruct.days_present = p->mystruct.working_days - p->mystruct.days_absent;
            p->mystruct.gross_salary = p->mystruct.basic - ((p->mystruct.days_absent / p->mystruct.working_days) * p->mystruct.basic);
            p->mystruct.pf = p->mystruct.gross_salary*0.1;
            p->mystruct.allowance = p->mystruct.gross_salary*0.55;
            p->mystruct.net = (p->mystruct.gross - p->mystruct.pf) + p->mystruct.allowance;
            p->mystruct.clerk_counter++;
            p->mystruct.counter++;
        }



    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
            if(p->mystruct.operator_counter == 1)
        {
            printf("sorry, you have already entered the details of all computer operators\n");
        }

            else

        {
            p->mystruct.designation = "computer operator";
            p->mystruct.basic = 9000;
            printf("enter no of days absent\n);
            scanf("%u", &p->mystruct.days_absent);
            p->mystruct.days_present = p->mystruct.working_days - p->mystruct.days_absent;
            p->mystruct.gross_salary = p->mystruct.basic - ((p->mystruct.days_absent / p->mystruct.working_days) * p->mystruct.basic);
            p->mystruct.pf = p->mystruct.gross_salary*0.12;
            p->mystruct.allowance = p->mystruct.gross_salary*0.75;
            p->mystruct.net = (p->mystruct.gross - p->mystruct.pf) + p->mystruct.allowance;
            p->mystruct.operator_counter++;
            p->mystruct.counter++;      
        }


    }

    else if (choice == 3)
    {
            if(p->mystruct.salesman_counter == 6)
        {
            printf("sorry, you have already entered the details of all salesman\n");
        }

            else

        {
            p->mystruct.designation = "salesman";
            p->mystruct.basic = 10000;
            printf("enter no of days absent\n");
            scanf("%u", &p->mystruct.days_absent);
            p->mystruct.days_present = p->mystruct.working_days - p->mystruct.days_absent;
            p->mystruct.gross_salary = p->mystruct.basic - ((p->mystruct.days_absent / p->mystruct.working_days) * p->mystruct.basic);
            p->mystruct.pf = p->mystruct.gross_salary*0.15;
            p->mystruct.allowance = p->mystruct.gross_salary*0.95;
            p->mystruct.net = (p->mystruct.gross - p->mystruct.pf) + p->mystruct.allowance;
            p->mystruct.salesman_counter++;
            p->mystruct.oounter++;      
        }


    }

else if (choice == 4)
    {
            if(p.->mystruct.salesman_counter == 3)
        {
            printf("sorry, you have already entered the details of all helpers\n");
        }

            else

        {
            p->mystruct.designation = "helper";
            p->mystruct.basic = 6500;
            printf("enter no of days absent\n);
            scanf("%u", &p->mystruct.days_absent);
            p->mystruct.days_present = p->mystruct.working_days - p->mystruct.days_absent;
            p->mystruct.gross_salary = p->mystruct.basic - ((p->mystruct.days_absent / p->mystruct.working_days) * p->mystruct.basic);
            p->mystruct.pf = p->mystruct.gross_salary*0.08;
            p->mystruct.allowance = p->mystruct.gross_salary*0.45;
            p->mystruct.net = (p->mystruct.gross - p->mystruct.pf) + p->mystruct.allowance;
            p->mystruct.helper_counter++;
            p->mystruct.counter++;      
        }


}

else
    {
printf("invalid choice, press 1 to continue\n");
scanf("%d", &proceed);
    }
        while (proceed);
    }
    }
    else 
    {
    printf("data entry complete");
    }
    }


}
void get_time()
{
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);

printf("now: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
}

void display()
{
printf("SALARY SLIP OF EMPLOYEES ";
printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
printf("empid\t name\t days_absent\t days_present\t gross_salary\t   PF\t allowance\t net");
printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
while(p.next!=NULL);
{
print(p.mystruct);
}
}
```